# Script detecting and resolving ngrok hostnames for updating noip A and srv dns records

Tags: dns, ngrok, srv, noip

Hello  I  have  tried  to  generate  code  with  ChatGPT to  make  a  script  which get  ngrok  hostname and  resolve  it to  ip  and  add  dns  A  record  and  SRV  record  for  noip  when  it  run  ,  but  it  only  can  add  dns  A  record  it  can  not  add  SRV  record .  Could  you  help  me  debug  the  code  and  give  me  the  correct  script  .  Heres  is  the  chatgpt  generated  python  code :

```
import requests
import socket
import subprocess

# Ngrok API URL
ngrok_api_url = "http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels"

# Get Ngrok information
try:
    response = requests.get(ngrok_api_url)
    response.raise_for_status()
    ngrok_data = response.json()
    print(response.text)  # Add this line to print the raw response from Ngrok
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(f"Error getting Ngrok information: {e}")
    exit()

# Extract public URL from Ngrok data
try:
    public_url = ngrok_data["tunnels"][0]["public_url"]
    ngrok_hostname = public_url.split(":")[1][2:].split('/')[0]  # Remove unwanted characters
    ngrok_port = public_url.split(":")[2]
except (KeyError, IndexError) as e:
    print(f"Error extracting Ngrok hostname and port: {e}")
    exit()

# Resolve Ngrok hostname to IP address
try:
    ngrok_ip = socket.gethostbyname(ngrok_hostname)
except socket.gaierror as e:
    print(f"Error resolving Ngrok hostname: {e}")
    exit()

# Update No-IP DNS A record
try:
    noip_hostname = ""  # Replace with your No-IP hostname
    noip_username = ""  # Replace with your No-IP username
    noip_password = ""  # Replace with your No-IP password

    # Update A record
    update_url_a = f"https://dynupdate.no-ip.com/nic/update?hostname={noip_hostname}&myip={ngrok_ip}"
    response_a = requests.get(update_url_a, auth=(noip_username, noip_password))
    response_a.raise_for_status()
    print(f"A record updated successfully.")

    # Update SRV record using subprocess
    subprocess.run(["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\No-IP\\DUC40.exe", "-U", noip_username, "-P", noip_password, "-d", noip_hostname, "SRV", ngrok_port])
    print(f"SRV record updated successfully.")
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(f"Error updating No-IP DNS records: {e}")
    exit()
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(f"Error updating SRV record: {e}")
    exit()

print(f"Ngrok IP: {ngrok_ip}")
print(f"Ngrok Port: {ngrok_port}")
```

I  would  like  a  script  which  when  I  run  get  ngrock  hostname resolve  it  to  ip    after  add  that  ip  to  my  DNS A  record  and  add  same  ip and  port  to  DNS  SRV  record

Comment: PM from ngrok here. We recently started [giving everyone a free domain](https://ngrok.com/blog-post/free-static-domains-ngrok-users) that doesn't change. You can claim yours in the [dashboard](https://dashboard.ngrok.com) and use it when starting a tunnel `ngrok http 80 --domain my-free-domain.ngrok-free.app`